# Split a vector into subverter of the same length and assign each of them to a new vector

Tags: r

Suppose that I have a vector as this:

```
s <- c(1:30) ## here the numbers are just an example. I just need to split it into the same length subvectors.
```

Then, suppose that I have other three vectors:

```
s1 <- s2 <- s3 <- vector()
```

I would like to split the first vector `s` into three subvectors each with `10` elements. Then, I would like to save each `10` elements in the vectors `s1:s3`. For example,

I would like to have this:

```
  > s1
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

> s2
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

> s3
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

I would like to do that with `lapply` because sometimes I need to split the vector to `10`, `3` or any arbitrary number of subvectors depends on my data.

Comment: Try `split(s, sort(s %% 3))`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` the `vector` 's' with a grouping index created with `gl`.  The output will be a `list` and it is better to keep it in the `list` instead of multiple objects in the global environment

```
lst <- split(s, as.integer(gl(length(s), 10, length(s))))
```

---

`gl` creates a grouping vector

```
as.integer(gl(length(s), 10, length(s)))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

and when split the 's' by the output of `gl`, the first 10 values of 's' are grouped together, then the second 10 and so on.  These are stored as `list` of `vector`s

Comment: could you please explain to me what does `gl` do?

Comment: @Maryam I updated with some description.  Hope it helps\